# Measure theory convergence in measure

Tags: convergence-divergence, sequence-of-function

If $f_n(x) $ be a sequence of measurable and finite almost everywhere functions on $[a, b] $ that is converging in measure   to $f(x)$ finite almost everywhere and measurable on [a, b]. If $ g(x) $is finite almost everywhere function and measurable on$ [a, b]$ then $g(x)f_n(x) $ converging to $f(x)g(x)$ in measure.
How can i prove that?  Any hint?

Answer (score 1):

Let $N$ be a set of measure zero such that $|g(x)|<\infty$ for all $x\in[a,b]-N$.

Assume that $f_{n}\rightarrow f$ in measure. Now fix a subsequence $(f_{n_{k}})$ of $(f_{n})$. As $f_{n_{k}}\rightarrow f$ in measure. Then there exists a further subsequence $(f_{n_{k_{l}}})$ such that $f_{n_{k_{l}}}(x)\rightarrow f(x)$ a.e.

Without loss of generality, we can assume that $f_{n_{k_{l}}}(x)\rightarrow f(x)$ for all $x\in[a,b]-N$. Then so is $f_{n_{k_{l}}}(x)g(x)\rightarrow f(x)g(x)$ for all such $x$.

This proves that $f_{n}g\rightarrow fg$ in measure.

The theorem used here is that, in a finite measure space, a sequence $(f_{n})$ converges to $f$ in measure if and only if for every subsequence $(f_{n_{k}})$ of $(f_{n})$, there exists a further subsequence $(f_{n_{k_{l}}})$ such that $f_{n_{k_{l}}}(x)\rightarrow f(x)$ a.e.

Comment: I think you used Riesz theorem but it's statement is not if and only if type.  If squence is converging to function in measure then there exists subsequence which converge pointwise almost everywhere to same function.

Comment: Actually that is the virtue of being finite measure space. You may search the above statement in any standard probability/measure theory book.

Comment: For example, Probability and Stochastic, Erhan Cinlar, page 102.

Comment: It is not true for sequence of measurable functions

Comment: You may try to look at Theorem 6.3.1 in S. Resnick's *A Probability Path*.